# How do I navigate through a method call hierarchy in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ide, navigation

I come from Eclipse, I would like to know if there is a way in Xcode 4 to navigate through method calls like there.
I know I can jump to the definition of a method, but I want to know who is calling that method/function.
The only way I've found is doing a regular text search, but that's not very helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146801/how-do-i-find-in-xcode-all-caller-functions-of-a-specific-function-like-eclipse

Answer (score 12):

Since Xcode 4.4 the feature to look up the immediate caller and/or callees of a method has been available. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a handy hierarchy view as there is in Eclipse.

[What's New in Xcode 4.4](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011649-SW1)

> Xcode can show the callers and callees of the current function or method. This function is accessed from the Show Related Items menu, or by using the Assistant editor and selecting Callers or Callees in the jump bar pop-up menu.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can find the callers and callees from the Related Files button in the upper left corner of the editor: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WEzB1.png. The hotkey is `Ctrl+1`.

Answer (score 9):

here is a visual how to find the caller(s).  Look for the little image i've highlighted in pink.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Doing a search is indeed the only way to check where in the code certain messages are being sent. Xcode doesn't have such a functionality. Keep in mind that even if it had, it couldn't be perfect because messages can be composed and sent dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, Objective-C is so "loose" that, even looking at the call, it's often hard to guess which method is being called.  Its one saving grace is that method names tend to be a hair more unique than in other languages, and they often end with ":", so text search isn't always a terrible approach.