# How do I find in Xcode all caller functions of a specific function like eclipse's Call Hierarchy?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

how do I find in XCode all caller functions of a specific function like eclipse's Call Hierarchy

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I navigate through a method call hierarchy in Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026824/how-do-i-navigate-through-a-method-call-hierarchy-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 13):

Since the release of XCode 4.4, this functionality exists and is called "show related items".
There are multiple ways of accessing the pop-up menu that will allow you to view all callers and callees, among other things.

The fastest way is:

1. Mark method in code (using your cursor or double click name)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
3. Select "Callers" from the pop-up menu

You can also go View->Standard Editor->show related items or press the tiny button just left of the arrow buttons in the line just above the editor window (where it shows your currently selected file and method).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Better answer than the duplicate listed above.

Comment: I wish I could give this more up-votes. Note that this works in Objective-C++ and C++ as well. Also note that it doesn't work for: IBActions that are only called by XIBs, init methods or C++ constructors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hotkey —> ^CmdShift + H

Comment: This is incredible. Find > Call Hierarchy is such a powerful tool.